# Match letter to corresponding number in list in Jython

Tags: python, list, jython

I'm looking at making a program, that when the user inputs a name as an argument it matches each letter to a corresponding number stored in a list.

For eg:

```
def nameNumbers(name):
    alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
  'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
  'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
  'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
  'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
  'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]
```

So if I was to pass in "Adam" it would return:

```
8.17
4.25
8.17
2.41
```

So far I've got this, but it only returns one item on list and needs the input to be exact:

```
    for letter in name:
     indexOfLetter = alphabetList.index(name)
     letterFrequency = alphabetList[indexOfLetter + 1] 
     print(letterFrequency)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slight change to your code

**Code**

```
def nameNumbers(name):
  alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
  'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
  'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
  'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
  'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
  'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]

  for letter in name:
     # Since each has upper followed by lower case
     # Use letter.upper() + letter.lower() since you have upper 
     indexOfLetter = alphabetList.index(letter.upper() + letter.lower())
     letterFrequency = alphabetList[indexOfLetter + 1] 
     print(letterFrequency)


nameNumbers("Adam")
```

**Output**

```
8.17
4.25
8.17
2.41
```

**Alternative**

The program should compute the numbers and the program print externally.

Also, the for loop can be replaced by more succinct list comprehensions.

```
def nameNumbers(name):
  alphabetList = ['Aa', 8.17, 'Bb', 1.49, 'Cc', 2.78, 'Dd', 4.25, 
  'Ee', 12.70, 'Ff', 2.23, 'Gg', 2.02, 'Hh', 6.09, 'Ii', 6.97, 
  'Jj', 0.15, 'Kk', 0.77, 'Ll', 4.03, 'Mm', 2.41, 'Nn', 6.75, 
  'Oo', 7.51, 'Pp', 1.93, 'Qq', 0.10, 'Rr', 5.99, 'Ss', 6.33, 
  'Tt', 9.06, 'Uu', 2.76, 'Vv', 0.98, 'Ww', 2.36, 'Xx', 0.15, 
  'Yy', 1.97, 'Zz', 0.07]

  indexes = [alphabetList.index(letter.upper() + letter.lower()) for letter in name]
  return [alphabetList[i+1] for i in indexes]

print(*nameNumbers("Adam"), sep="\n")
```

Same output as above.

Comment: Thanks so much! How come letter.upper() + letter.lower() works when used together?